# How to import huge data from tsv to MySQL using jdbc faster?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have two huge tsv files(10mil records) where tsv one file has the attributes id, name, age and other had attributes id, email and phno.
I tried to read the first file and insert the records into the Person table  and then read the second file and update the Person table. This approach takes time as the table is first inserted with 10 mil records and then they are updated. IS there any other way to speed this process?
P.S some Id are not there in the 2nd tsv file so I was not able to merge both of them .

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I think at the end of the day inserting a lot of data takes time.  You might look to distributing your load over a number of clients connecting to the database.  However I suspect you will need to look to your JDBC driver and what can be configured there.
One thing that might help is using raw JDBC rather than JPA/Hibernate as you are looking to only use inserts.  finally rather than guess where the bottlenecks are run a profiler you might be surprised where you can make performance gains.

Comment: One answer goes into details about using LOAD DATA to get the first huge file loaded.  Please explain further about the second file.  Is it about the same file?  Are you really "updating" or perhaps "replacing"?  What is the criteria for the "update"?  The point is that _probably_ SQL would be much faster than JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't try **LOAD DATA INFILE** which is a highly optimized, **MySQL**-specific statement that directly inserts data into a table from a **CSV** / **TSV** file.

There are two ways to use **LOAD DATA INFILE**. You can copy the data file to the server's data directory (typically */var/lib/mysql-files/*) and run:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/products.csv' INTO TABLE products;
```

Or you can also store the data file on the client side, and use the LOCAL keyword:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/products.csv' INTO TABLE products;
```

[High-speed inserts with MySQL](https://medium.com/@benmorel/high-speed-inserts-with-mysql-9d3dcd76f723)

You should also check [MySql Documentation - LOAD DATA Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)
And you could use a statement like this one:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' 
  INTO TABLE tbl_name
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;
```